# Category Quantity Discount for Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, discount

If I have many products on one category and I want to give discounts for specific quantity like: 2 for 10% off, 3 for 15% off and 4 for 20% off in any product they purchased on that same category.

I've tried to find extensions in opencart but I didn't found one. Does anyone knows any extension for this in opencart?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a place to ask for software recommendations.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  You should try http://forum.opencart.com/ or contact a developer for commercial support here http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=support/support

Answer (score 0):

This features is already exits int the open cart system.
Go to that product form in the admin panel,
`Home -> Product->` In product form there is a Discount tab,you can set price for every product according to the quantity.

Comment: This does not answer the question: "any product they purchased on that same category"

Comment: yes but this doesn't answer the question he is asking.

Comment: I think he wants ,product discount according to the product's quantity..So if it is in same category or not is it really matter ?Basically he needs product discount according to their quantity.